# ISession doesn't contain a definition for 'Get'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to use HttpContext.Session.Get in my code and that gives me"ISession doesn't contain a definition for 'Get'" and the same for 'set' so I don't know what I miss

I am learning how to build simple e-commerce by getting a list of chosen products into an order report.

and I did use:

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
```

but still, get the same error

controller

```
  namespace EshopTest5.Controllers
    {
        public class OrderController : Controller
        {
            private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
            private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpcontext;
    
    
            public OrderController(ApplicationDbContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpcontext)
            {
                _context = context;
                _httpcontext = httpcontext;
            }
    
            
    
            // GET: OrderController/Checkout
            public IActionResult Checkout()
            {
                return View();
            }
    
            
    
            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    
            public async Task<IActionResult> Checkout(Order anOrder)
            {
                List<Product> products =_httpcontext. HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Product>>("products");
                if (products != null)
                {
                    foreach (var product in products)
                    {
                        OrderDetails orderDetails = new OrderDetails();
                        orderDetails.PorductId = product.ProductId;
                        anOrder.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetails);
                    }
                }
    
                anOrder.OrderNo = GetOrderNo();
                _context.Orders.Add(anOrder);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                HttpContext.Session.Set("products", new List<Product>());
                return View();
            }
```

program:

```
using EshopTest5.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddSession();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseSession();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A generic `Get<T>` method doesn't exist for `ISession`, but there's an implementation of this as an extension-method in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-and-get-session-values) that you can use:

> ```
> public static class SessionExtensions
> {
>     public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
>     {
>         session.SetString(key, JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
>     }
>
>     public static T? Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
>     {
>         var value = session.GetString(key);
>         return value == null ? default : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
>     }
> }
> ```

Add the preceding code to a `SessionExtensions.cs` file, perhaps in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace.